# What is happening when I have two CSP (Content Security Policies) policies - header & meta?

Tags: security, web, browser, content-security-policy

*Question is regarding having [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) served twice:*

What's the behavior if there is one policy served through the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP response header and also another policy specified with the `<meta />` element?

Will those two be merged somehow? Or else which one has priority? (I cannot find clear info on this in the spec).

Specific use case might be serving `Report-to` through the HTTP response header and putting all other restrictions in the `<meta />` element — because some of those are generated by webpack - and if I shouldn't be worried about `<meta />` shallowed by the HTTP response-header policy.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you have CSP directives specified both in a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header and in a `meta` element, the browser uses the most-restrictive CSP directives, wherever specified.

See the details on multiple polices at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#multiple-policies and details on using the `meta` element at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element:

> A policy specified via a `meta` element will be enforced along
> with any other policies active for the protected resource, regardless
> of where they’re specified. The general impact of enforcing multiple
> policies is described in *§8.1 The effect of multiple policies*.
>
> #### 8.1. The effect of multiple policies
>
> The impact is that adding additional policies to the list of policies
> to enforce **can only further restrict** the capabilities of the protected resource.