# Is this method of applying content security policy ok?

Tags: html, angularjs, security, xss, content-security-policy

I am trying to add CSP to my web application, I have added the following meta tag in my index page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:;default-src *;style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
```

and Also the following my my web.config file on IIS:

```
<customHeaders>
     <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://*.domain.com;
                                                img-src 'self' http://*.domain.com data:"  />

      </customHeaders>
```

Is it necessary to add both meta tag and additional headers? or One of them is sufficient?

Does the meta tag policy override the custom header?

Does this `script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` mean that I can write inline JavaScript and use `eval` function inside my code? Does this rule override the policy set by headers? (because as far as I know in headers I have prohibited usage of inline JavaScript and `eval` function)

And my last question is if I use these settings, Should I use `ng-csp` or its other variant `ng-csp="no-unsafe-eval"` in my html?

Comment: If this implementation is to remediate flaws highlighted in Veracode and you still continuing 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' won't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to add both meta tag and additional headers? or One of them is sufficient?

One is sufficient. If you can make your server send the policy in a response header, that’s better. You don’t need to also specify anything in a `meta` element too, and there’s no advantage to it.

> Does the meta tag policy override the custom header?

The `meta` policy will only override the header policy if the `meta` policy is stricter. See this answer:

[What is happening when I have two CSP (Content Security Policies) policies - header & meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148998/what-is-happening-when-i-have-two-csp-content-security-policies-policies-hea/51153816#51153816)

… which cites a part of the CSP that says, *“adding additional policies to the list of policies to enforce can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource”*.

> Does this `script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` mean that I can write inline JavaScript and use `eval` function inside my code?

It would do that if your header also specified those values for `script-src`. But your header policy does not. So the browser uses the strictest policy, regardless of where it’s specified.

> Does this rule override the policy set by headers? (because as far as I know in headers I have prohibited usage of inline JavaScript and `eval` function)

No, as the *[What is happening when I have two CSP (Content Security Policies) policies - header & meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148998/what-is-happening-when-i-have-two-csp-content-security-policies-policies-hea/51153816#51153816)* answer explains, you can’t override a strict policy by specifying a less-strict policy elsewhere.

So you’re best off specifying all your policy values in just one place, in a header (instead of `meta`).