# Does inline <meta> Content-Security-Policy affect policy from server?

Tags: html, http, request, meta, content-security-policy

A Content-Security-Policy can be on the set server and delivered in the HTTP header to the client. The Content-Security-Policy can also be set inline in the HTML in a `<meta>` tag.

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src;">
```

Does the inline policy affect the policy set in the header?

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153816/441757. Browsers enforce the most-restrictive policy directives, regardless where they’re specified. So if a `<meta>` policy has more-restrictive directives than a header policy, the browser enforces those more-restrictive directives. But if the `<meta>` policy has less-restrictive directives than the header policy, the browser effectively ignores the `<meta>` policy directives, & just uses the (more-restrictive) directives in the header policy. Likewise, if the `<meta>` policy is more restrictive, the header policy directives are ignored.