# Issue when Content-Security-Policy is present in both HTTP header and a meta tag

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, cross-domain, content-security-policy

We are working on a web project where the Content Security Policies are enforced via HTTP headers and via meta tags as well. There is a default set of properties which are a part of the HTTP header and each page specifies the additional policies by means of a meta tag in the document header.

One of the page in the project loads content inside an iframe. The Content-Security-Policy in the HTTP header for that page is

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-src *;`

and the page has the following meta tag in it's document header

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src none;"/>`

It is mentioned in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) that the fallback order is `frame-src` -> `child-src` -> `default-src`. In-spite of setting `frame-src` in the HTTP header, I get the following error message in the browser console (Tried on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge):

```
Refused to frame '<url here>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src none". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Also,

> Moving both the policies either to the HTTP header or to the
>   meta tag works as expected

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153816/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker Yes. I saw that answer earlier. That does not explain the fact that the fallback policy can be chosen if the actual policy is not present at the second place (meta tag in my case). To be more clear, since there was a `frame-src *` in the HTTP header in my case but there was no corresponding policy in the meta tag, so a fallback `default-src` was chosen. Barry's answer below helped me to understand this better. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more general page above that frame-src one on [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Multiple_content_security_policies) explains what you are seeing:

> **Multiple content security policies**
>
> CSP allows multiple policies being specified for a resource, including via the `Content-Security-Policy` header, the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header and a `<meta>` element.
>
> You can use the `Content-Security-Policy` header more than once... Adding additional policies can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource.

So with multiple CSPs, it’s like *all of them are in play* and  **not**, as you seem to want, that they are combined into one combined policy. So in your example, you effectively have `frame-src` set to `none` (since you have a `default-src` and no specific override for `frame-src`) so opening it up later does not work.