Content Security Policy Error: Refused to Execute Inline Script
I'm working on a React application where I’m trying to integrate particles.js for a visual effect. While everything works perfectly in my local development environment, I’m running into a Content Security Policy (CSP) issue when I deploy to production.
In my production environment, I'm using the following CSP meta tag in the HTML:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" >

When I check the production environment, I encounter the following errors in the console:
Refused to load the script 
'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"default-src 'self'". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to execute inline script 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, 
a hash ('sha256-sE1QKI+3nnpP92ZRF6Ro5DLUkDvouqP/XSbFGAbo0ZU='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. 
Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Locally, I set my Content Security Policy (CSP) to allow only self and the CDN for particles.js. It prompted me to add 'unsafe-inline' to allow inline scripts, and that fixed the issue.
However, when I deployed to production, the same setup didn’t work. The external script from the CDN is still blocked, and I can’t get particles.js to load. I’m unsure why it works locally but not in production. Any help would be appreciated!

What CORS headers is your server configured to send in production?

Is there any Content-Security-Policy header sent in the response from server when the page load?

If there is a CSP in the server response as well then that could be a problem. Your local server might not have that csp header. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153816/4342075

Thank you for all the suggestions! I managed to resolve the issue earlier today without needing to use the http-equiv Content Security Policy meta tag.
The solution was to download the actual particles-min.js file and store it in the same directory as my index.html, so I didn't have to rely on the external link from cdn.jsdelivr.net.
As for the second error, I moved my inline script into an external particles-config.js file, and called it from there. Everything worked perfectly on the production server!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="particles.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="particles-config.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

